# How to crop STL file online

Tags: php, html, stl, three.js

I am very new to PHP & HTML, now I am dealing with a 3D mesh. I am using Three.js to make it view online. Is there a possibility to crop or cut an STL file and save it on my server using Three.js?

Comment: Just to give you heads up; your problem has nothing to do with php or html.

Comment: Your question is not clear;
1-) Are you able to load stl file so far?
2-) How are you going to crop it? Based on what?

Comment: @Zagoda I am able to load file using `threejs` cut using bounding box or cut using lines

Comment: google stl exporter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just assuming you don't have/ know how to use Blender, so check out the tools in https://clara.io/

in the modeling tools there should be an option to cull points based on another piece of geometry - so what you could do is create a cube that encompasses everything you want to keep and then do a boolean operation to keep everything inside the cube and toss everything outside.

I don't know the exact name of the operation or how to do it, but I know it's possible and that it's actually a 3D question not a code based one, unless you want to do this cropping dynamically, and if that's the case, modify your question to reflect that.